# TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined (Passing this.array to callback function)

Tags: typescript, callback, this

How to fix this code in TypeScript (ES5+) such that the callback function of `readInterface.on()` can access the `lines` array declared outside the function?

```
const readline = require('readline');
const fs = require('fs');

const readInterface = readline.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream("data.list"),
  output: false,
  silent: true,
  console: false
});

var lines: string[] = [];

readInterface.on('line', function(line) {
  if (line && line.indexOf("#") !== 0) {
    this.lines.push(line);
  }
});

lines.forEach(line => {
  console.log(line);
});
```

Edit:

### The solution

In fact this question posed to problems to tackle. The first error was resolved by @Andreas by outlining that the `this` keyword should be removed from the line `this.lines.push(line);`

The desired outcome of the question, however, was to synchronously return the lines read by the asynchronous function `readInterface.on('line', function(line) { ... });`, with the misunderstanding that the function was actually synchronous.

The solution was to use the synchronous alternative `readlinesSync` from a package available on npm as [readlines](https://www.npmjs.com/package/readlines).

```
const readlines = require('readlines');

var _lines: string[] = readlines.readlinesSync('dat/test.list');
var lines: string[] = [];

_lines.forEach(line => {
  if (line && line.indexOf("#") !== 0) {
    lines.push(line);
  }
});

lines.forEach(line => {
  console.log(line);
});
```

Comment: `line.indexOf("#") !== 0 && line` - The other way round would make more sense

Comment: Why did you add `this`?

Comment: console.log(lines[0]); still returns undefined without adding `this`.

Comment: That's a different problem, hence a separate question -> [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Constantly changing the question doesn't help - especially not when you remove the source of the problem/question

Comment: None of the modifications reflect on the answer to the question anyway. How would you change the code above such that it compiles without an error? Please answer that if it's possible.

Comment: See below. And as already said, the _"why is lines[0] still `undefined`?"_ -> That's a different problem, hence would require a different question which would then be closed as duplicate from the link I've mentioned in my third comment

Comment: Thank you, though that question is about returning a response.
This question is about mutating a globally declared property from within a callback function.

Comment: No it is not: _"TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"_

Answer (score 2):

```
readInterface.on('line', line=> {
  if (line.indexOf("#") !== 0 && line) {
    this.lines.push(line);
  }
});
```

Using arrow functions in typescript helps you to point the right **this** reference. Else you reference the closure you are currently in.

Comment: _"Else you reference the function you are currently in"_ -> [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `this` in `this.lines.push()`

```
readInterface.on('line', function(line) {
  if (line && line.indexOf("#") !== 0) {
    lines.push(line);
  }
});
```

-> [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: this only fixes the first half of the problem. running `console.log(lines[0]) after the call to corrected readInterface.on() still returns `undefined`.

Comment: As already said _twice_. That's the answer to the problem in your title/question. The "second half" is a different problem (-> hence a different question) which I've also "answered" _twice_...